# How to find mean of the this probability density function

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, random-variables, expected-value

How to calculate the mean of

$f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{2.4\cdot 10^{10}} {{(x+2000)}^4}$  and $x > 0$

I thought I should use the expected value for the random variable but I couldn't solve the integral, any suggestions?

Below is my work, I couldn't go further since I forget some basic Calculus. Any tips?

$E(X)=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}xf(x)dx = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}x\frac{2.4\cdot 10^{10}} {{(x+2000)}^4}dx$

Comment: Could you please show any integration work you've done?

Comment: $f(x)$ is not a probability density function, as its integral from negative infinity to infinity is not $1$. Do you in fact want the [average value](http://www.mathwords.com/a/average_value_function.htm) of the function over a given interval ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. If you don't add the work you've done, this will get closed for lack of context, if you do, you might get help addressing the specific issue you're having.

Comment: @Clarinetist Edited

Comment: @WaveX Sorry, I forgot to add the interval

Comment: Hint: let $u = x+2000$. Then $\text{d}u = \text{d}x$, and $x = u - 2000$. Be sure to change your limits of integration to the interval from $2000$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks!